# ckeditor entities html database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor with CodeIgniter and I configured the editor to send the HTML character, but the tags are not being sent correctly
[image]

This is the Controller for insert database:

```
public function create()
{
    $extra = array(
        'return' => "{$this->_route}index/",
        'success_message' => lang("{$this->_language}:submit_success"),
        'failure_message' => lang("{$this->_language}:submit_failure"),
        'title' => lang("{$this->_language}:create"),
    );
    //$this->streams = 'htmlspecialchars',
    $this->streams->cp->entry_form($this->slug_stream, $this->namespace, 'new', null, true, $extra);
}
```

this is the configuration of the ckeditor in the config.js file

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For the complete reference:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config
    config.entities_latin = false;
    config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false;
    config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
    config.basicEntities = false;
    config.entities_additional = '#1049';
    config.entities = false;
    config.specialChars = [ '&quot;', '&rsquo;', [ '&custom;', 'Custom label' ] ];
    config.specialChars = config.specialChars.concat( [ '&quot;', [ '&rsquo;', 'Custom label' ] ] );
    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // Remove some buttons, provided by the standard plugins, which we don't
    // need to have in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
};
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that inserts the data to the database?

Comment: look and update my question, the data is sent via the controller

Comment: No I mean the code that inserts the data to the database, are you escaping HTML before inserting to the database?

Comment: First off, what exactly is the text you are trying to submit? It wouldn't happen to be php tags would it? Secondly @mehdi is right, you should post all the relevant code from the input to where it is put into the db. In your controller I don't even see your post data.

Comment: what it identifies is the configuration of the ckeditor because it is when it takes the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello I found a solution, which is where it is rendered in the view to approve the html_entity_decode,

```html
'description' =>html_entity_decode($item['description'])
```